# TIBCO Performance Measurement

Tags: performance, tibco

Is there a way where I can measure the time taking for a particular node in the TIBCO workflow process?
e.g - How much time did the JMS/ Database node take to complete its operation?

Answer (score 1):

The following goes for Tibco Business Works:

a) In tibco Administrator, you can see the time elapsed for each individual activity.

Service Instances > BW Process > Process Definitions.

Select each process after running it once and you will get an Execution count, Elapsed time and CPU time for each activity than ran.

b) If you are only interested in a single activity, you can add two mapper activities in the flow, one before and one after the node you want to measure, and assign to them a value of tib:timestamp(). Their difference will give you the elapsed time in miliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You might enable statistics in TIBCO Administrator for the deployed engine
(Engine Control Tab) -> Start Statistic Collection.

This will produce a CSV on local disk (the path is also displayed there) with details of elapsed time of all activities of the executed processes of your engine.

You might use this data for detailed analysis then.